# How can I make this code simplier?

Tags: mysql, sql

Iam trying to make my code simple, is there any difference between this

```
INSERT INTO course (code, name, credits) VALUES 
('WSD','Web systems Development','75');
INSERT INTO course (code, name, credits) VALUES 
('DDM','Database Design & Management','100');
INSERT INTO course (code, name, credits) VALUES 
('NSF','Network security & forensics','75');
```

and this?

```
INSERT INTO course (code, name, credits) VALUES 
('WSD','Web systems Development','75');
('DDM','Database Design & Management','100'); 
('NSF','Network security & forensics','75');
```

Does it produce same results?

Comment: Second query will not work.

Comment: Test it and find out?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, the same.

You can insert multiple rows at once in MySql but instead of a semicolon you need commas.

Syntax

```
INSERT INTO tbl_name
        (a,b,c)
    VALUES
        (1,2,3),
        (4,5,6),
        (7,8,9);
```

Your example

```
INSERT INTO course (code, name, credits) 
VALUES
('WSD','Web systems Development','75'),
('DDM','Database Design & Management','100'),
('NSF','Network security & forensics','75');
```

Comment: You are right that in terms of speed it is not the same.  However I was looking at it as the end result of what is in the database is still the same.  Thank you.